# How to perform internal dataframe or matrix calculations as a dataframe or matrix is being generated inside a Tidyverse map() function?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, tidyverse

I started using the tidyverse `map()` function for building lists with embedded dataframes and matrices. The code below creates the `createBucketMap()` function which works fine for calculating the first two columns ("Inflow" and "Due") of the rendered multiple dataframes as shown in the first image below for the first rendered dataframe, whose calculations draw on lists and vectors external to the `createBucketMap()` function per lines of code `alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]` and `rate <- rates[[matL_name]]`.

Now I'm trying to insert into the `createBucketMap()` function the code for populating the rest of the dataframe columns with calculated values as the dataframes are built by the function. In the code below you can see in my comments what I'm trying to get each rendered dataframe column to do. My novice temptation is to use a series of `dplyr` `mutate()` statements outside of `map()` to add the columns with related calculations starting with "Cover_due" through "Outflow", but it appears clumsy. Is there a clean way to do this using `map()` or any other `tidyverse` function consistent with the `map()` structure used in the below code to populate these dataframe columns?

These calculated columns I'm trying to include are internal dataframe calculations in that they refer to other columns in the same dataframe, and not outside the dataframe. The kind of thing `mutate()` excels at.

Just one example calculation for the "Cover_due" column will give me the start I need. "Cover_due" should be equal to the lesser of the values in the same row of "Inflow" and "Due".

Below is the first rendered list/dataframe item when running the `map()` code in this OP, where only the first two columns are calculated and populated:

[image]

Below is the correct output per a long and clumsy for-loop solution that doesn't use `map()` and all fields correctly calculated and populated:

[image]

Code:

```
seriesVector <- function() {c("mat_One", "mat_Two")}
matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"), mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.4), mat_Two = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6))
flowVector <- c(6, 5, 600) # was 4
balVector <- c(1000, 900, 800)
rates <- list(mat_One = 0.10, mat_Two = 0.20)

library(tidyverse)

createBucketMap <- function() {
  imap(matList, \(matL, matL_name) {
    map(matL, \(x) {
      alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]
      rate <- rates[[matL_name]]
      data.frame(
        Inflow = flowVector * alc,
        Due = balVector * alc * rate,
        Cover_due = 0, # minimum of Inflow and Due in the same row
        Shortfall = 0, # equal to “Due” minus “Cover_due” in the same row
        Begin_cum_shortfall = 0, # equal to prior (lagged) row of col “End_cum_shortfall” except that in row 1 “Begin_cum_shortfall” is zero
        Cover_cum_sfall = 0, # equal to lesser of (a) “Inflow” minus “Cover_due” and (b) “Begin cum_shortfall”, all in the same row
        End_cum_shortfall = 0, # equal to “Shortfall” plus “Begin_cum_shortfall” minus “Cover_cum_sfall” all in the same row
        Outflow = 0 # equal to “Inflow” minus “Cover_due” minus “Cover_cum_sfall”, all in the same row
      ) |>
        as.matrix()
    }) |>
      set_names(matL)
  })
}
createBucketMap()
```

Comment: Why not use `mutate` **inside** `map()`? Something like `map(matL, \(x) { alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]; rate <- rates[[matL_name]]; data.frame(Inflow = flowVector * alc, Due = balVector * alc * rate) |> mutate(Cover_due = pmin(Inflow, Due), Shortfall = Due - Cover_due, ...) |> as.matrix()`

Comment: It makes me nervous that your function takes no arguments and relies on finding all of its needed inputs in the global environment. I'd recommend giving the function all of its inputs, or a list of its inputs, so that it's more flexible. But I don't know the context in which you're running it...

Comment: I tried the `mutate()` inside `map()`  but gave up when I tried `Begin_cum_shortfall = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 0, lag(End_cum_shortfall))` which gives only 0's. Tried indexing it for the first row but no luck.  All the other mutates work! My problem with `Begin_cum_shortfall` is it reaches back (lags) one row and I need to address when we're calculating the first row where it's value MUST BE 0. As for your other comment, I use the function with no arguments temporarily while I work on it. Will include arguments later after I figure out `map()` and `lag`.

Comment: See the `?lag` help page, you can set the default. `Begin_cum_shortfall = lag(End_cum_shortfall, default = 0)`. And make sure you define them in the correct order, your code shows `Begin_cum_shortfall` **before** `End_cum_shortfall`, which won't work. You can reorder the columns after defining them if needed.

Comment: OK, I had tried `lag(End_cum_shortfall, default = 0)` but didn't have it in the correct order so it didn't work. I reordered and now all mutates work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply define the variable as free standing before collecting them in the frame.

```
seriesVector <- function() {
  c("mat_One", "mat_Two")
}
matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"), mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.4), mat_Two = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6))
flowVector <- c(6, 5, 600) # was 4
balVector <- c(1000, 900, 800)
rates <- list(mat_One = 0.10, mat_Two = 0.20)

library(tidyverse)

createBucketMap <- function() {
  imap(matList, \(matL, matL_name) {
    map(matL, \(x) {
      alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]
      rate <- rates[[matL_name]]

      { # the various calculations 
        Inflow <- flowVector * alc
        Due <- balVector * alc * rate
        Cover_due <- pmin(Inflow,Due)
      }
      #collected 
      tibble(
        Inflow,
        Due,
        Cover_due
      ) |>
        as.matrix()
    }) |>
      set_names(matL)
  })
}
createBucketMap()
```

Comment: If you're going to do this way, there's no point in the `tibble`. Replace with `cbind(Inflow, Due, Cover_due, ...)` and a matrix will be created directly (skip the `as.matrix()` also). It will be a bit more efficient, too.